# How to separate lines in my design?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustration, pathfinder

I have this skull design that I made by drawing a line in the middle, then drawing objects on the left side and then copy-pasting them to the right side.

For some reason, lots of lines collided into one object and now I can't separate them. Since I can't separate them, I cannot delete the line in the middle because it deletes half of the design.

Somehow I managed to delete only part of the middle line, but I'm struggling to delete the rest. Could you please help?

Edit: All of the objects are ungrouped. Also, when I tried deleting anchor points, it deletes the lines that are near, too.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hard to see exactly what's going on. Try pressing Ctrl/Cmd + Y to enter *Outline Mode*. There it's easier to see the actual shapes. Use *Direct Selection Tool* (the white arrow) to select individual points.

Comment: Really difficult to give direction without seeing the actual file... but.. select all, grab the Shape Builder tool, hold down the Option/Alt key and drag across lines you *don't* want. -- Might work.

Comment: use white arrow tool

Answer (score 0):

Nobody will be able to tell you *exactly how*, because this is an artwork specific method. Generally, you will need to use the Direct Selection Tool in Outline Mode and you will probably need to merge some paths (using Shapebuilder, Pathfinder, etc).

If everything is ungrouped as you mentioned, try to move the OK parts of the artwork to a new layer, and hide this layer. This will isolate the problem areas so you can focus on the clean-up.